# Customizing a GCE Ubuntu VM image

Tags: google-compute-engine, sudo, google-cloud-platform

I have a Google Cloud Platform account that I access from a VirtualBox VM. I am using the Google Compute Engine for a project that I am currently working on, and I had to create a custom image based on the Ubuntu 14.04 image that's available there.

I made changes to the Ubuntu image by ssh'ing into an Ubuntu 14.04 instance, (from my Vbox VM terminal) installing the Matlab compiler runtime, and downloading some other files that I needed. I created the custom image by following the steps according to the documentation.

However, now the changes I made are only available to me when I SSH from my Vbox VM terminal. I need to be able to run a certain matlab program Via startup scripts, how can I make it so that all users using this image have access to the customizations I made? Is there a way I can do this without having to make the edits by ssh'ing from the developers console and redoing all the changes?

**EDIT:** I don't think I was very clear so Ill give some examples. say my Google account is `alexanderlang`. When I ssh into an instance created from my custom image from the developers console, bash prompt looks like:

```
alexanderlang@myinstance $
```

My Vbox username is `alex`, and when I ssh into the same instance from my vbox terminal, bash prompt looks like:

```
alex@myinstance $
```

`alex@myinstance` can run matlab programs, but `alexanderlang@myinstance` cannot. I'm talking about the same instance, created from the same image. I think this might have something to do with the ssh keys for my custom image, but I don't know how to change or remove those keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you connect to your VM instance via ssh by using either Developers Console or `gcloud`, the user account is dynamically created (if it doesn't already exist) by setting metadata on the VM. The question is: **how does each tool choose your username?**

When you use Google Developers Console, the only information it knows about you is your Google Account name, so it uses that, e.g., `<first-name>_<last-name>` or similar.

When you connect to your instance via `gcloud`, it knows the value of `$USER` so it uses that instead.

Note that in either case, your account has passwordless `sudo` access, so if you want to switch from one account to the other, you can run:

```
sudo su alex
```

while logged in as `alexanderlang` and then you have access to all the programs that `alex` does.

Similarly, you can run:

```
sudo su alexanderlang
```

while logged in as `alex` to do the reverse.

---

Startup scripts run as `root`. To run commands as another user, you need to do two things:

- change to that username
- run commands as that user

`sudo su alex` will create a new shell and hence ignore the rest of the script (until you manually exit the user shell, which is not what you want).

You can use `sudo su alex -c 'command to run'` but since what you want to run is a complex script, you need to first save the script to a file, and then run it.

Your options are:

1. pre-create the shell script to run
2. dynamically generate it from the startup script

Doing (1) is easy if the script never changes. For frequently-changing scripts (and it sounds like, many dynamically created VMs), you want to use option (2).

Here's how to do this in a startup script:

```
cat > /tmp/startup-script-helper.sh <<EOF
# ... put the script contents here ...
EOF

sudo su alex -c '/tmp/startup-script-helper.sh'
```

Comment: so if I put sudo su alex at the beggining of my startup scripts, will that do the trick? Im basically trying to automate some heavy computation via a matlab program in the cloud, so I cant have to manually type in any code as I could be spawning thousands of vm's at a time

Comment: @AlexLang — no, that will spawn a new shell, and the rest of the commands will be ignored. I've updated my answer with how to do this, it's longer than what can fit in a comment.

Comment: So it turns out that my main mistake was using `~`  to specify my home directory when I should have been using `/home/alex/`. oops. leaving your answer as the correct one though because it applies more generally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Packer](https://packer.io/) to create a derived image from a stock GCE VM image. Packer will let you do the following very easily:

- boot a GCE VM using an image you specify
- run some customization step, e.g., shell script, or Chef/Puppet/etc.
- save the resulting image in your Google Cloud Platform project

Then, you can boot any number of new VMs using your newly-created image.

Note that since your VM image will be stored on Google Cloud Storage, you will be charged for the space it uses. [Current pricing](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing) for Google Cloud Storage standard class is USD $0.026 / GB / month. A typical VM image should be less than 1GB.

You can see a complete example of how I used Packer to build VMs and pre-installed Ambari on it via [my GitHub repo](https://github.com/mbrukman/cloud-launcher/tree/master/apps/hortonworks/hdp2/ambari/packer).

Comment: Thanks @Misha, but this doesnt really answer my question. Ill make and edit to make it more clear.

Comment: @AlexLang — sorry, that wasn't clear from the original question formulation. I've added another answer as it's now a completely different question, but I think this answer still has value to folks not familiar with Packer, so I'll leave it here for reference.